# docker swarm join connection error from other instance and local pc

Tags: docker, networking, docker-swarm, swarm

I gave role like this.

env: oracle cloud.
open port:  TCP 2377 , UDP TCP 7946 ,UDP 4786

Instance A : manager
Instance B : worker
Local PC : worker

init swarm mode with this cli on A

```
docker swarm init  --advertise-addr <A's IP>
```

B got

```
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp A's IP:2377: connect: no route to host"
```

Local PC got

```
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp A's IP:2377: connect: connection refused"
```

well I have no idea what should I need to do more.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

the problem was firewall setting on manager node's instance.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=2377/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: This works for me. But i ran this in both machines.

Answer (score 1):

for me @Logan Lee solution perfectly matched.

According to the docker documentation, following ports need to manage accordingly

> ```
> TCP port 2377 for cluster management communications
> TCP and UDP port 7946 for communication among nodes
> UDP port 4789 for overlay network traffic
> ```

Thanks  @Logan Lee

Comment: lovely to get feed back from here ! lol thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the network connectivity between A and B, seems like  they are not on the same network.